# Got an error when running rake db:create in Docker

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql, docker

I'm new in Docker then followed their official tutorial in running Ruby on Rails and Postgresql. Everything is okay when I run `docker-compose up` but when I tried the command `docker-compose run web rake db:create`, I got an error of  `FATAL:  role "root" does not exist`.

```
database.yml

default: &default
  adapter: postgresql
  encoding: unicode
  pool: 5
  host: db

development:
  <<: *default
  database: myapp_development

test:
  <<: *default
  database: myapp_test

production:
  <<: *default
  database: myapp_production
  username: postgres
  password:
```

Answer (score 0):

You are running the command as root and it is trying to connect to the database with the same username. You have not created a user root in PostgreSQL so you have to do so.

I would suggest creating another username and using that for connecting, even though the name root has no special meaning in PostgreSQL, but it is usually better to have separate users/roles for each system.

You need to modify the database connection settings to reflect the new username.

Answer (score 0):

I think it's better to set up environment value for `RAILS_ENV` in your `docker-compose.yml`

Answer (score 0):

If you're using the official postgres image [from the docker hub](https://hub.docker.com/_/postgres/) then the default username for the postgres server that starts when you run a container based on that image is "postgres" and the password is not needed. You should update your yaml file to look like this:

database.yml:

```
    default: &default
      adapter: postgresql
      encoding: unicode
      pool: 5
      host: db
      username: postgres

    development:
      <<: *default
      database: myapp_development

    test:
      <<: *default
      database: myapp_test

    production:
      <<: *default
      database: myapp_production
```

Assuming that all three databases are running on the same container (db) and that container has been linked as "db" to your rails/application container.